# Predictions function of ROCR package gives Error: 'predictions' contains NA

Tags: r, analytics, na, roc, edx

I have been following the [Edx course The Analytics Edge](https://www.edx.org/course/the-analytics-edge) and I am currently in the logistic regression section: Framingham Heart Study part.

Here they use the predictions function of the `ROCR` package to predict the data accuracy with the threshold value set to 0.5. I have downloaded the .csv file from the edx course portal and written the exact same code but I am getting the error that 'Predictions' contains NA.

Here's the code:

```
framingham <- read.csv("framingham.csv")

library(caTools)

# framingham <- na.omit(framingham) # If I use this line then the code works fine but people must be working all the time with data with missing values. So, it should work for all the cases too. 

set.seed(1000)

split <- sample.split(framingham$TenYearCHD, SplitRatio = 0.65)

train <- subset(framingham, split == TRUE)

test <- subset(framingham, split == FALSE)

framinghamLog <- glm(TenYearCHD ~ ., data = train, family = binomial)

summary(framinghamLog)

predictTest <- predict(framinghamLog, type = "response", newdata = test)

table(test$TenYearCHD, predictTest > 0.5)

library(ROCR)

ROCRpred <- prediction(predictTest, test$TenYearCHD)
```

This is the error:

```
Error: 'predictions' contains NA.
```

Comment: Are you asking us whether or not there are NA values?  How to remove the NA values?  Whether there's been an error in the code that caused the NA values?  Embed the code in your question to make it clearer ... we don't want to open your link.

Comment: My question is that databases must have missing data all the time. So is it necessary to omit the NA values or is there a way to handle this situation?